# Change default value to "Select All" after another parameter changed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

**EXPLAINATION**

I have 2 parameters in SSRS report: `Year` and `Month`

**AVAILABLE VALUES**

Available values are selected from dropdown list (could be multiselected values).

`Year` available values are selected with SQL query;

`Month` available values are from 1 to 12.

**DEFAULT VALUES**

Default values for now are:

`Year` expression: `=YEAR(NOW())`

`Month` expression: `=MONTH(NOW())`

**WHAT I NEED**

If for parameter `Year` user change default value and select 2 or more values (*i.e. 2015 and 2016*) It automatically should select all values for `Month` parameter (*select from 1 to 12*)

Also I have custom value in both parameters: `All`, if value `All` is selected It's the same as select all values from the list.

How can I achieve It?

Comment: do you have a stored proc currently that you are using. if so could you post it so I can see what its doing?

Comment: For parameters I'm using simple queries...For `Year` i'm using `SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(DateNeeded)  FROM Tbl WHERE Etc = etc2` and for  `Month`: `SELECT 'All' as MonthNo UNION ALL SELECT '2' UNION ALL SELECT '3'...`

Comment: No what I meant was how are you returning the result set to the report?

Comment: And why It's matter? Simple procedure with select, from and where clauses...

Comment: The reason is I want to know  in what format are you going to pass the parameters to the underlying stored proc to retrieve your result set.

Comment: Without complete informations its hard to help you bro.